# R - How to change all values except last 1 to NA in a group

Tags: r

I would like to change all values in a group called `value` to NA except for the one associated with the largest value in another column called `orderid`. I am not sure where my code is going wrong. As an example, I have this dataset:

```
customerid <- c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4")
orderid <- c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1")
value <- c("negative", "negative", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "negative")
df <- data.frame(customerid, orderid, status)
```

I want to change it to:

```
customerid <- c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4")
orderid <- c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1")
value <- c(NA, "negative", NA, "positive", NA, NA, "positive", "negative")
df <- data.frame(customerid, orderid, status)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `case_when` in `mutate` instead of `ifelse` - [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) is the documentation

Comment: I get an error when I use `mutate(value = case_when(orderid = max(orderid) ~ value, TRUE ~ is.na(value)))`  ..."Case 1...must be a logical vector, not a character vector." Any recommendations on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  You just need to change your true statement in `ifelse` to `NA` instead of `is.na(value)`.  `is.na(value)` tests whether an object is `NA` and returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  In your case you want to overwrite the value to `NA`.   `case_when()` is the `dplyr::` way of doing things, but `ifelse()` also works.  Here is a reproducible example using `ifelse()`

```
if(!require(dplyr)){
  install.packages("dplyr")
}


customerid <- c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4")
orderid <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1)
value <- c("negative", "negative", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "negative")
df <- data.frame(customerid, orderid, value)

df1 <-  df %>%   
  arrange(customerid, orderid) %>% 
  group_by(customerid) %>% 
  mutate(status = ifelse(orderid == max(orderid), value,NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: When I run this code, the positives and negatives still don't get changed to NA. Any recs?

Comment: Oh, yes.  You read your numbers in as characters.  Let me quickly fix my answer and it should work

Comment: Even when I changed the numbers from characters to numbers, the positives and negatives still don't get changed to NA for some reason.

Comment: Yes, it turned our to be because `orderid` was in the `group_by()` so if each combination of `customerid` and `orderid` is a single group, then `orderid` will always be the max value.  Removing the `orderid` from `group_by()` solved the issue,

Comment: Thank you so much! That was such a silly mistake on my part. Appreciate it!